# Why I getting error while installing npm?

Tags: npm, terminal, solidity, npx, hardhat

Unable to install npm. It is showing error, files are unable to download. I tried this with multiple platforms like gitpod, codespaces and vs code but everytime, It is unable to download. Please help me to download npm.

`@harshit81201 ➜ /workspaces/codespaces-blank $ npm i
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /workspaces/codespaces-blank/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspaces/codespaces-blank/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/codespace/.npm/_logs/2023-07-29T10_01_05_109Z-debug-0.log`

[This is error I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZH7l.png)

I tried to install npm on many platforms like gitpod, codespaces and vs code. But, always I return with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is no `package.json` file in that path of your project. If it's your project and you want to create a new `package.json`, so you can install packages, type `npm init`.

If it's not your project and you downloaded it somewhere, there's either a `package.json` in another directory (maybe a sub-directory) or you don't need npm.

Comment: it is not working still getting same error even after adding files and adding commands that you have mentioned.